# Adding two addEventListener in a row

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I'm trying to invoke a function by waiting til the content of the page is load and triggered by a click by the user. Here is what I have:

```
function get_content(){
var element = document.getElementById("v0");
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
console.log(text);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', function () {
document.getElementById("v0");
      .addEventListener('click', get_content);
});
```

Is the document.getElementById("v0") making it so that the user must click on that specific element? Because that element is generated via a XmlHttpRequest. 
I'm more thinking in the lines of when the user clicks and generates the DOM, it will log the text content by itself.

The code doesn't work and I don't exactly know why.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend that you should edit your post - it is not entirely clear what you mean when you say "the code doesn't work"

Comment: Did you meant document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ }, false); ?

Comment: Simply remove the `;` before `addEventlistener` and after `("v0")`...

Answer (score 0):

If `v0` element is generated by dynamically after document ready event, then you must bind that event after creating element or you have to use bubble propagation (create click callback for example for body element, and then explicitly check element clicked).